# What are the possible ways to keep a user logged in the application in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, state

I am developing on a flutter project and the project consists of a login screen and home screen and some other additional screens. I'm using `firebase authentication` for my authentication purposes in the login screen.

Now when i login to the application and it will route me to the homepage as required. But after i close the application and once i reopen the application, i'll have to login again to the application. How can i permanently keep the user logged in after the user logs into the application after the first time. (In other words, i want to keep the user logged in and keep the user in the home page after user once logs into the application, eventhough the user closes and reopen the app).

For a further reference, i will attach my `login.dart` , `auth_services.dart` , `wrapper.dart` files.

`Login.dart` :

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController emailController;
    TextEditingController passwordController;
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    emailController = TextEditingController();
    passwordController = TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                        width: 300,
                        height: 380,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/logo.png',
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 25.0, right: 25.0, top: 0, bottom: 0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter the email.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    controller: emailController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                        ),
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.mail),
                        labelText: 'E-Mail',
                        hintText: 'admin@gmail.com'),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 25.0, right: 25.0, top: 15, bottom: 0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter the password.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    controller: passwordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                        ),
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
                        labelText: 'Password',
                        hintText: 'Enter your Password'),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 100,
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState == null) {}
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        authService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                            context,
                            emailController.text.trim(),
                            passwordController.text.trim());
                      }
                      // authService.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                      //     context,
                      //     emailController.text.trim(),
                      //     passwordController.text.trim());
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Login',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )),
                MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => forgotPassword()));
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Forgot Password',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, color: Colors.red.shade900),
                    ))
              ])),
        ));
  }
}
```

`auth_services.dart` :

```
class AuthService {
  //Creating an instance of firebase.
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User? _userFromFirebase(auth.User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return User(user.uid, user.email);
  }

  Stream<User?>? get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  Future<User?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    BuildContext context,
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    try {
      final credential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return _userFromFirebase(credential.user);

      throw Exception('Some Error occured. ');
    } on auth.FirebaseAuthException catch (e, _) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(e.toString()),
      ));
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(e.toString()),
      ));
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

`wrapper.dart` :

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: authService.user,
        builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            final User? user = snapshot.data;
            return user == null ? Login() : dashboard();
          } else {
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Thank you all so much in advance.

Comment: By default, auth persistence is set to local and they shouldn't be logged out unless they explicitly do or account is disable. Could you provide some code that is not working as intended?

Comment: Firebase already persists the user credentials on most platforms, and restores is when the app restarts/page reloads. If this is not happening for you, edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Dharmaraj  I've included my code for a better understanding.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've. included my code for a better clarification.

Comment: Oof... so much code. I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because I expect that at least half of this code is not needed to reproduce the problem (through it is undoubtedly useful in your app).

Comment: Focusing on what I said in my answer, if you `listen` to `_firebaseAuth.authStateChanges()` and print the user you get there, are you seeing it fire with `null` (only)?

Comment: Sorry about the long code, i'll use minimal next time.  And yes, i am able to get the firebase UID.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase already persists the user credentials on most platforms, and restores is when the app restarts/page reloads. But this requires a call to the server, so is an asynchronous operation, so be sure to listen for `authStateChanges` as shown [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state) to get notified once the user has been restored.

If this is not happening for you, edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: PS: Some examples from @PaulRuiz (former Firebaser) can be found on his [Medium page](https://medium.com/@ptruiz): in particular https://medium.com/firebase-developers/dive-into-firebase-auth-on-flutter-email-and-link-sign-in-e51603eb08f8

Comment: Good one @RenaudTarnec.   I was trying to get email-link sign-in working in Dartpad yesterday (unsuccessfully because of domain issues) and should've read Paul's article for sure. :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create a variable **Boolean** like `isLoggedIn` and when user logs in you can assign the value true to it and also you have to save it `locally` using local storage like **SharedPreference**.

After then when of `isLoggedIn` is true or not is true means already `logged` in otherwise `not`.